# Difference between : and := with variables in bash files

Tags: bash

I came across a bash file which has something like this

```
MYVAR := SomeVal
```

I know after reading some tutorials you set values as such

```
MYVAR = SomeVal
```

What is the difference between the above two ?

Comment: You should know that you don't put a spaces around the assignment operator.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a Makefile?

Answer (score 3):

You probably saw a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to set a default value.

The difference is whether the variable is unset or it is set with a null value:

1. when the variable is unset, there's no difference

   ```
   $ unset MYVAR; : ${MYVAR:=SomeVal}; echo "$MYVAR"
   SomeVal
   $ unset MYVAR; : ${MYVAR=SomeVal}; echo "$MYVAR"
   SomeVal
   ```
2. when the variable has a value, there's no difference

   ```
   $ MYVAR="foo"; : ${MYVAR:=SomeVal}; echo "$MYVAR"
   foo
   $ MYVAR="foo"; : ${MYVAR=SomeVal}; echo "$MYVAR"
   foo
   ```
3. when the variable has null value:

   ```
   $ MYVAR=""; : ${MYVAR:=SomeVal}; echo "$MYVAR"
   SomeVal
   $ MYVAR=""; : ${MYVAR=SomeVal}; echo "$MYVAR"
   # empty line
   ```